# Width of FontAwesome icons varies in Xamarin Forms, causing parent properties to be wider than I want

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, label

[image][image]

I have a LightGray PancakeView that has a FontAwesomeLabel inside of it. The size of the labels widths vary, and I want to know if there is a way to keep it a static width without clipping the FontAwesomeLabel.

```
new Frame
{
   Content = new StackLayout
   {
       Spacing = 10,
       Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,

       Children =
       {
          new PancakeView
          {
              Padding = 18,
              CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(15),
              BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray,

              Content = new FontAwesomeLabel
              {
              }.Bind(FontAwesomeLabel.TextProperty, path: "FAIconHex")     
    
           }.CenterExpandVertical()
           .Center()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: set a `WidthRequest` value on the `Label`

Comment: This worked. I used `HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center` in order to center any FontAwesome labels that drifted off to the left since some are smaller than others. Thanks.